# How to add a new node without prefix

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm working with a SOAP API that requires some XML nodes without prefixes.  Is it even possible to do with Nokogiri? Simply omitting the prefix from the node name makes Nokogiri use the default prefix "env".

```
node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('WageReportsToIR', envelope)
envelope.xpath('//env:Body').first.add_child(node)
```

results

```
<env:Body>\n    <env:WageReportsToIR/>\n  </env:Body>
```

Do I have any other option but to write a regex to remove the prefixes after I'm done editing the XML with Nokogiri?

Comment: I believe there's a method called `strip_namespaces` that does what you want

Comment: There is a `remove_namespaces` method for the document, but not for a node. Found out that nodes have `namespace=` method that accepts `nil` as a parameter. It removes the namespace and prefix. But is really cumbersome to call for each node after you have created it.